# Where is Intel speed select driver?

Tags: linux, kernel, drivers

According to

https://builders.intel.com/docs/networkbuilders/intel-speed-select-technology-base-frequency-enhancing-performance.pdf

page 11, linux support SST-BF since 4.20

but I can't find it's related code in github:

https://github.com/torvalds/linux

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Accroding to 
https://github.com/intel/CommsPowerManagement/blob/master/sst_bf.py#L121

Get the SST-BF base frequencey

```
base_filename = "/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu" + str(core) + "/cpufreq/base_frequency"
```

linux 4.20 intel pstate source code:

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.20/source/drivers/cpufreq/intel_pstate.c#L739

```
cpufreq_freq_attr_ro(base_frequency);
```

This line of code only added since 4.20